# Slick: could not find implicit value for parameter e: slick.jdbc.SetParameter[Option[java.util.UUID]]

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm workihng with Play! 2.5, Slick 3 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

I'm trying to use a simple plain `SQL` query with an optional `UUID` but I get this error:

```
Slick: could not find implicit value for parameter e: slick.jdbc.SetParameter[Option[java.util.UUID]]
```

My case class looks like

```
final case class GaClientId(ip: String, userId: Option[UUID], clientId: String)
```

And my query like this:

```
db.run(       
  sql"""
    INSERT INTO ga_client_id(ip, user_id, clientId) VALUES (
    ${gaClientId.ip}, ${gaClientId.userId}, $gaClientId.userId.orNull)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;""")
```

I tried to add this:

```
implicit val getUUIDContent: GetResult[GaClientId] =
  GetResult(r => GaClientId(r.<<, r.nextStringOption().map(UUID.fromString), r.<<))
```

but without result.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

As the error implies you should specify `SetParameter` not `GetParameter`. It should be as follows:

```
  implicit val uuidSetter = SetParameter[Option[UUID]] {
    case (Some(uuid), params) => params.setString(uuid.toString)
    case (None, params) => params.setNull(Types.VARCHAR)
  }
```

And then you should probably add `asUpdate` to your update `SQL`:

```
  db.run((sql"""
      INSERT INTO ga_client_id(ip, user_id, clientId) VALUES (
      ${gaClientId.ip}, ${gaClientId.userId}, ${gaClientId.clientId})
      ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
  """).asUpdate)
```

Comment: It compiles, but I have to cast the VARCHAR to a UUID in order not to have a PostgreSQL error (with ${gaClientId.userId}::uuid). I suspect that there is a way to do it without do uuid to varchar tp uuid but I didn't find it.

Comment: So you are saying you have UUID as a type of the field in DB?

Comment: Yes, exactly (sorry if my question was not clear about that)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @Paul Doelga, you can additionally try

```
  db.run((sql"""
      INSERT INTO ga_client_id(ip, user_id, clientId) VALUES (
      ${gaClientId.ip}, ${gaClientId.userId}::uuid, ${gaClientId.clientId})
      ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
  """).asUpdate)
```

I originally got the answer from

https://github.com/skinny-framework/skinny-framework/issues/301

I guess the main reason of the failure is that Postgres need a parameter in type `UUID`, but `JDBC` doesn't support it, so you have to convert it to `String`, and convert back to `UUID` in SQL.